# mk:1: *** missing separator. android NDK

Tags: android, c++, c, android-ndk

I am trying to compile some source code but when i run the command

**make -f android-9-armv7.mk**

I get the following error
android-9-armv7.mk:1: *** missing separator.  Stop.

This is the contents of the file above:
And I have set the IMAGINE_PATH variable as well, cant seem to figure it out.

> link ../imagine/make/shortcut/common-builds/android-9-armv7.mk

Compiling instructions
http://code.google.com/p/emu-ex-plus-alpha/wiki/Compiling

Imagine is locaed at C:/Imagine

Comment: Why don't you use the ndk-build command?

Comment: Running ndk-build results in 

 Your APP_BUILD_SCRIPT points to an unknown file: C:\android-ndk-r8c/jni/Android.mk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know where you've taken the sources, but all the `android-9-armv7.mk` files from different projects on that git has following content:

```
../imagine/make/shortcut/common-builds/android-9-armv7.mk
```

...there is no `link` keyword, which probably is why you get this error.

Also, please be informed that you're building this on *Windows* machine while documentation clearly states that it's supported only on *Linux* and *Mac OS X*.

Comment: I completely missed the linux part, i thought cygwin would be sufficient on windows. Ill just install a linux distro then, thanks for the help.